# Hiding Field Value in XML & making it as href

Tags: odoo

I want to hide actual field value in xml and make it as href in my xml form.

Just like  Visible Link ...

TIA

Comment: What kind of field? What do you mean by "hiding field vale"? Don't you want the value to appear as a label of the link?

Comment: Hi Ludwik.It is a Char FIeld. My  field value is like 'www.abcdefgh.com"..Now I want to make it as "click here" . How can i do this?

Comment: You would need to [create a custom widget for the field](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/howtos/web.html), I think.

Answer (score 0):

Odoo forms support an URL widget:

```
<field name="my_field" widget="url" />
```

See the field "Website" on the Partners/Customers form.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I know this widget. This only makes my field value as URL. But my problem is to hide actual field value and show a dummy url in place of my field.

Comment: You should improve your question. Your solution to use a field for the stored value, and a computed field to use for display value.